# Do chained ADFS STS authenticate each domain involved?

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, adfs2.0

I was recently reading this blog post about chaining multiple ADFS STS together: http://blogs.technet.com/b/dmitrii/archive/2012/08/18/chaining-multiple-sts.aspx

In case the link goes dead, the author describes chaining together multiple ADFS instances to give a set-up like:

- Claims enabled app
- Relying partner STS - fs1.external.com
- Replying partner STS - fs2.contoso.com
- IdP STS - fs1.contoso.com

When a user logged into the claims enabled app, they would hit each STS and eventually the IdP where they would get authenticated. At that point the authentication is passed back through the different STS to the user.

In this scenario, is the domain of each STS authenticated? I.e. is a cookie issued for fs1.external.com, fs2.external.com, fs1.contoso.com or just the IdP domain (fs1.contoso.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the IDP domain.

Note however, that on the downstream path:

- each ADFS can augment the token with claims
- the token is re-minted
  and signed with the signing key for that instance